# How to convert JPG files to one JPG file

Tags: image-manipulation

I have several JPG files from a PDF file, so concatenating the JPG files need to be "under each other". How can I do this?

Comment: maybe "montage" do it from imagemagick.. but how?

Comment: Do you know about ImageMagick?

Comment: ROWS="4"; montage -density 300x300 -tile 1x$ROWS *.jpg output.jpg

but it produces low quality images..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ROWS="4"; montage -geometry 2550 -tile 1x$ROWS *.jpg output.jpg
```

geometry -> you need to know the original picture width, or at least give this a good value so the quality could be enough

tile -> how many "columns x rows" will the output have? (from the original jpg files) - $ROWS could be calculated with "ls -1 *.jpg | wc -l" if one folder contains all the jpg files.

*.jpg -> input jpg files

output.jpg -y the output jpg

Comment: Small explanation and link to montage website could improve your answer a lot.